# Sikuli is unable to recognize image taken by snipping tool with the one on the screen while running auto testing

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-x

I am very new with Sikuli framework. I am trying to use Sikuli for GUI testing. I have taken the screen image shot using snipping tool for gmail login page and the same image i am using while running the test cases.
But it seems somehow, Sikuli framework is not able to match the image on the screen with below error:

```
FindFailed: C:/Rohit_Work_Dir/bdd_fw_workspace/cucumberwithrobotfw/src/test/java/com/learn/sikulimpl/emailId.png: (397x82) in S(0)[0,0 1280x720] E:Y, T:3.0
  Line 2759, in file Region.java

    at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2759)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:2336)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromTarget(Region.java:3213)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3698)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.keyin(Region.java:4366)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.type(Region.java:4328)
    at com.learn.sikulimpl.LoginGmailAccountSteps.loginToGEAccount(LoginGmailAccountSteps.java:58)
```

NOTE:

- I am using eclipse as IDE for the testing.
- I have created maven project with Sikula api version along with Selenium:

  ```
     <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
           <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.1</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>com.github.vidstige</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jadb</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use high quality images, but maybe your tool compress them. Just use Sikuli IDE and your problem will be solved.